# How do I solve the error on scrapy.clawer

Tags: python, django, scrapy

Now, I develop web app with django and scrapy that has function of searching English word. When I input word with form on django, scrapy get the mean of transltated word into Japanese from internet dictionary.

After inputting word ,activating scrapy and stop runserver, happning the error following:

```
[scrapy.crawler] INFO: Received SIGINT, shutting down gracefully. Send again to force
```

```
Error: That port is already in use.
```

I can stop it by using command `kill` , but it is inconvinient to input command everytime happens error. So I want to know how to solve it like adding code etc.

following is my code .

```
def add_venue(request):
    submitted = False
    if request.method =='POST':
        form = VenueForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data['word']#入力した単語
            queryset = Newword.objects.filter(word = name)
            print(queryset)
            if queryset.exists():
                #コード未記入
            else:
                #print(name)
                process = CrawlerProcess({
                'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'
                })

                process.crawl(WordSpider, query=name)#入力した単語をnameに入れて、スクレイピングを実行。
                process.start() # the script will block here until the crawling is finished
                form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/list/')
    else:
        form = VenueForm
        if 'submitted' in request.GET:
            submitted = True
    return render(request, 'form.html', {'form':form, 'submitted':submitted})
```

```
python3 manage.py runserver --nothreading --noreload
```

```
class WordSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'word'
    allowed_domains = ['ejje.weblio.jp']
    # start_urls = ['http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/']
  

    def __init__(self, query='', *args, **kwargs):
        super(WordSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        #self.user_agent = 'custom-user-agent'
        self.start_urls = ['https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/' + query]



    def parse(self, response):
       
        # item=ElscrapyItem()
        # item['word']=response.xpath('//*[@id="summary"]/div[2]/p/span[2]/text()').get().replace('\n', '').strip()
        # yield item
        
        word=response.xpath('//*[@id="summary"]/div[2]/p/span[2]/text()').get().replace('\n', '').strip()
        #loader = ItemLoader(item = ElscrapyItem(), response=response)
        #loader.add_xpath('word', '//*[@id="summary"]/div[2]/p/span[2]/text()')
        #yield loader.load_item()
        yield{
            'word':word
        }
```

django project is in scrapy project.

Comment: You probably don't want to use a subprocess for the crawler at all. Can you show the code for `WordSpider`?

Comment: I added WordSpider

Answer (score 0):

It's not a great idea to start [a whole Twisted reactor, thread pool, and everything CrawlerProcess entails](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/52d93490f57d4b2284e3d95efa5c622ab8ad16cb/scrapy/crawler.py#L271) in your request.

You don't need Scrapy at all to parse a single page; use `requests` and `bs4` (BeautifulSoup) instead.

```
import requests
import bs4


def get_word(query: str) -> str:
    resp = requests.get(f'https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/{query}', headers={
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)',
    })
    resp.raise_for_status()
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'html.parser')
    return soup.find(class_='content-explanation').get_text(strip=True)


print(get_word("cat"))
```

prints out

```
猫、ネコ科の動物、陰口をきく女、意地悪女、ジャズ狂、男、やつ
```

so plugging that into your view (and simplifying it a bit):

```
def add_venue(request):
    submitted = ('submitted' in request.GET)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = VenueForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            word = form.cleaned_data['word']
            if not Newword.objects.filter(word=word).exists():
                explanation = get_word(word)
                # (do something with `explanation` probably?)
                form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/list/')
    else:
        form = VenueForm()
    return render(request, 'form.html', {'form': form, 'submitted': submitted})
```

Comment: By the way, why not use scrapy?
And, I don't know two process generate when scrapy activates in django.

Comment: Just because Scrapy is overkill for a single page. I was actually wrong about the subprocess, but I think your original problem stems from CrawlerProcess leaving some auxiliary threads up, which cause issues with the rest of the Django process.

Comment: I see.  if I develop app with scrapying for multiple pages, Had I better use scrapy or another way? In the case of scrapy, How do I use it ?
Is this the correct way to use it?
https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html

Comment: In the context of a web application, it would be better to relegate scraping to a background task in an entirely separate process instead of running it in the request and having the user need to wait for it to finish (if it ever finishes). You could use e.g. rq, huey, celery, etc.

Comment: OK. I appreciate you for your advise. If I have any problems, I want to ask you.